# Refering to ViewController nested in Navigation & Tab controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have several view controllers nested in NavigationControllers and a main Tab Controller. Here's the Image:

The Look of the Storyboard:

[image: The Look of the Storyboard]

I would like to define an NSObject in the first ViewController (main), but I have to refer to it in the app delegate.

```
 let myStore = MyStore()
 let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
 let mainViewController = tabController.navigationControllers.first.rootViewController as! MainViewController
 mainViewController.myStore = myStore
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Originally I had no tab controller just one navigation controller, and It worked like this:

```
 let myStore = MyStore()
 let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
 let mainViewController = navController.topViewController as! MainViewController
 mainViewController.myStore = myStore
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property navigationControllers on a `UITabBarController`.  There is a navigationController (singular) but that refers to it's owning navigation controller not the ones in the tab.

If you want to refer to the tab navigation controllers you have to use the `viewControllers` property of the `UITabBarController` which is an array of them all.  You can then go through them and find the one you want.

Better yet you could create a proper data model that holds the data separately.

Comment: Oh.. so it is more useful to use Core data model to store data?

Comment: That depends on what you are storing.  If it's a lot of data that needs to persist then perhaps you could look into something like that.  If you are just storing some data to use while your app is running then you probably don't need to go that far just have a better data model inside the app (perhaps a singleton, factory class, etc)